# Command to list all .java files in a specific sub-folders in windows

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to get all .java file paths from specific sub-directories using
`dir /b /s *.java` command.
Is there any way I can get all java files only from specific sub-directories using dir command?

Something like this: `dir /b /s "codebase/**/src/**/*.java"`.

```
-codebase
--project1
---src/../xx.java (I want this)
---test/../yy.java (but not this)
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to perform the recursive search for `*.java` in `codebase`, then use `find.exe` to match those containing `\src\ `. Please also note that this is not a 'nix based system, and you're not parsing a URL, Windows uses back slashes as directory separators.

Comment: or I suppose, you could also use `find.exe`, _or `findstr.exe` if you prefer it_, to exclude those containing `\test\ `, _(if exclusion makes more sense to your situation than inclusion)_.

Comment: `dir /b /s | findstr /IRC:"\.java" | find /i "\src\"` remove `/i` from find if the path must only be in lowercase `\src\`